# BLE loss of Data packets in smartphone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Am working on a BLuetooth Low energy module embedded in a custom board . whenever i press an interrupt (push button) the ble module advertises some number once and goes to sleep ,again when interupt given it advertises the next number(incremented value) once and goes to sleep .These values are scanned in a custom android app running in nexus 5.Though the phone is scanning most of the packets ,sometimes it fails to capture some datapackets.the custom board advertises once and goes to sleep ,the phone must be able to capture this advertisement packets,but some times it miss the data packets. So my question is Is it normal that the BLE compatible phones cannot capture all datapackets from a pheriperal device i.e there may be loss of some data packets.Or is it the problem with smart phone nexus 5 ble hardware.

Comment: This is radio we are talking.  Unless you add some higher level protocol data loss is to be expected.  And even with higher level protocols things could of gone out of range so you have to expect failure and on the range limit more failure than success.

Comment: It is not Out of Range issue .The setup is placed near the phone ,still Phone couldnt capture all datapackets. Could you explain in brief what do you mean by higher level protocol .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE is transmitting with low power on in a crowded spectrum. Some packet loss is to be expected (though I agree it is more than I'd like).

A higher level protocol will detect packet loss and request retransmission. In the case of BLE, instead of using advertisments for data you can actually connect to the device and then use notifications. These are far more reliable and shouldn't be dropped. The downside is most devices only support connecting to a handful of peripherals, usually 7. Listening for advertisments doesn't require connection and therefore there's no fixed limit to the number of advertisers you can listen to.

The packet loss also depends on what is listening. A nRF51822 trasmitting to my Nexus 4 with Android 5.0 at zero range gets >50% PLOS. When transmitting to another nRF51822 it gets around 20% PLOS. I guess the Nexus 4 tries to save power so maybe it doesn't listen continously.

Comment: for our custom application broadcaster mode is mandatory & advertising is done only once ,so the smartphone(nexus 5) should capture that packets without any loss. Is there any possibilities to overcome this issue other than pairing & connecting .because the nrf sniffer application (using nrf51822 dongle)in windows captures the packets from all the three channels,even if it misses in one channel other two channels are captured !

Comment: Yeah there's no way you can remotely guarantee packet delivery sending only 3 packets on different channels. I don't see why you couldn't send more than 3 packets though. If necessary you could ditch the soft-device and control the radio manually. It's documented and transmitting BLE advertisments is simple enough. Then you could send many packets quickly and hope more get through (probably not following the Bluetooth spec then but I don't see why it wouldn't work). Why can on you only send one advertisment?

Comment: The application can transmit maximum of one advertisement only  due to some critical power saving issues.So we have to capture it witout missing.                                                                   my thinking smart phone ble may be missing some packets when data is transmitted at the time of scan interval(am not sure whether is it correct ). what will be the scan interval for nexus 5 bluetoothLE. I downloaded the android source code to search the scan interval value,but still i couldnt find it.Right now we are using android level 4.3.1 api,is there any issue in using 4.3.2 api?

Comment: Are you *sure* it couldn't transmit at least a few advertisments (say 20)? I think that would still use less than a micro-amp-hour. I'm intrigued what your application is now. The only thing I can thing that would have so little power is maybe one of those energy harvesting switches. They're just a gimmick though - even a coin cell would give you at least a decade of battery life.

Comment: nope it should transmit only one.and it operates on generic battery which is also used for other applications a lot ! so is the scan interval as mentioned in previous comment is an issue? also how to change the scan interval of in the android source code

Comment: I don't think you can change the scan interval or window manually, though Android 5.0 does let you choose between [latency-optimised, power-optimised and balanced scanning modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.html#SCAN_MODE_BALANCED) which I imagine would affect them (though it might just affect how often the device is woken up if sleeping). I think you're over-estimating [how much energy a BLE advertisment uses](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra347a/swra347a.pdf). We're talking a few 10s of nano-amp-hours here. Insignificant compared to anything else.

Comment: Thankyou Timmmm .i will checkitout asap .

Comment: what is the meaning of PLOS?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, that only some data packets were arriving. It seems that enabling the SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY mode with ble scanner helps - your device will keep listening continously, so no data will be missed (unless there is clutter, bad range etc. like Timmmm suggested).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings

hope this helps

Comment: This was incredibly helpful! I looked for a solution for days to fix the issue!